# Page Redirect after X seconds wait using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to redirect to specific url after 5 seconds after putting an error message. First i have used Javascript as below.

```
document.ready(window.setTimeout(location.href = "https://www.google.co.in",5000));
```

But it is not waiting for 5 seconds. Than I searched the issue in google than come to know that "document.ready()" is invoked when document is loaded at DOM, not at web browser.

Than i have used window.load() function of jQuery but still i am not getting what i want.

```
$(window).load(function() {
               window.setTimeout(window.location.href = "https://www.google.co.in",5000);
            });
```

Can anyone please let me know how exactly i need to do to wait for 5 seconds.

Comment: For a complete solution: [js redirect](http://insider.zone/tools/client-side-url-redirect-generator/)

Comment: While it is a javascript-question, it sure seems like the HTML-alternative should be mentioned. `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='https://www.google.co.in/'" />`

Answer (score 149, accepted):

It looks you are almost there. Try:

```
if(error == true){

    // Your application has indicated there's an error
    window.setTimeout(function(){

        // Move to a new location or you can do something else
        window.location.href = "https://www.google.co.in";

    }, 5000);

}
```

Comment: An html alternative

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4; URL=../device_user/email_keyboard_one_pint.html">

Comment: Thanks, I combined it with PHP: if ($row_cnt>0)
{ echo "Already posted!"; echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1; URL=new.php'>";
exit(); }

Answer (score 44):

You actually need to pass a function inside the `window.setTimeout()` which you want to execute after 5000 milliseconds, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = "https://www.google.co.in";
    }, 5000);
});
```

For More info: [`.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Comment: Beat me to it. The redirect doesn't wait because the location is being assigned immediately. It has to be a function call

Answer (score 37):

You can use this JavaScript function. Here you can **display Redirection message to the user** and redirected to the given URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    function Redirect() 
    {  
        window.location="http://www.newpage.com"; 
    } 
    document.write("You will be redirected to a new page in 5 seconds"); 
    setTimeout('Redirect()', 5000);   
</script>
```

Answer (score 11):

Use JavaScript `setInterval()` method to redirect page after some specified time. The following script will redirect page after 5 seconds.

```
var count = 5;
setInterval(function(){
    count--;
    document.getElementById('countDown').innerHTML = count;
    if (count == 0) {
        window.location = 'https://www.google.com'; 
    }
},1000);
```

Example script and live demo can be found from here - [Redirect page after delay using JavaScript](http://www.codexworld.com/redirect-page-after-delay-using-javascript/)

Answer (score 10):

You need to pass a function to `setTimeout`

```
$(window).load(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "https://www.google.co.in";
    }, 5000)
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = "https://www.google.co.in"},5000);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
setTimeout('Redirect()', 1000);
function Redirect() 
{  
    window.location="https://stackoverflow.com"; 
}
```

//document.write("You will be Redirect to a new page in 1000 -> 1 Seconds, 2000 -> 2 Seconds");

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function idleTimer() {
    var t;
    //window.onload = resetTimer;
    window.onmousemove = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
    window.onmousedown = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
    window.onclick = resetTimer;     // catches mouse clicks
    window.onscroll = resetTimer;    // catches scrolling
    window.onkeypress = resetTimer;  //catches keyboard actions

    function logout() {
        window.location.href = 'logout.php';  //Adapt to actual logout script
    }

   function reload() {
          window.location = self.location.href;  //Reloads the current page
   }

   function resetTimer() {
        clearTimeout(t);
        t = setTimeout(logout, 1800000);  // time is in milliseconds (1000 is 1 second)
        t= setTimeout(reload, 300000);  // time is in milliseconds (1000 is 1 second)
    }
}
idleTimer();
        </script>
```