# URL link slide show

Tags: javascript

is it possible to create URL web page slide show? For example, I have the first link and i want to redirect to another link with a certain amount of time automatically. So, this two link must repeat with the mentioned time. Is there a way for this? Thank you.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150171/page-redirect-after-x-seconds-wait-using-javascript

Comment: do you need the link text to change too?

Comment: No. I'm not sure how to say it. It's like two URL links become like slide show in timely manner.