# redirect to home page after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i created a simple login that the user will fill in and after successfully
login he will redirectly go another page that has a message login successful, Now 
my problem is after the user redirect to the login success massage page is there 
a way to set 3seconds on that page and after that the user will go back to home page after 3 seconds? hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: That's not the right way to do it, but you can use `setTimeout(function(){ window.location = '/home'}, 3000)`, for this kind of requests i recommend you learn more about promises

Comment: just out of curiosity why can't you show your homepage directly?

Comment: This is poor UI design, don't make the user wait for anything. Just redirect back the home page immediately. Logging in should only generate an unavoidable message if the login fails.

Comment: im just doing what my adviser want. haha

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Page Redirect after X seconds wait using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150171/page-redirect-after-x-seconds-wait-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use setTimeout to set time after which user will be redirected and window.location to set the URL where the users should be redirected

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com"; },3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location = "you Home Page URL";
            }, 3000);
        });
    </script>
```