# PHP Submit form with cURL data and tracking code auto-redirect on timer

Tags: php

I am currently working on a form that has specific user related data on curl call which is why "$form->data" line is required. I have to add a tracking code (google) to a thank you page that needs to auto redirect after a certain time on the page. So the process would be like this:

1. User completes form.
2. Form redirects to thank you page with tracking code.
3. Thank you page redirects to login page after say 10 seconds.

Here is the code I currently have on the thank you page, that as far as I know does not trigger the Google tracking code because it redirects immediately:

```
<?php header('Location: '. $form->data['curl_data']->url );
die(); ?>
```

I also tried via javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
window.setTimeout(function () {
location.href = $form->data['curl_data']->url; }, 5000);
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: redirect using javascript? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-use-JavaScript-to-redirect-a-webpage-after-5-seconds

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150171/page-redirect-after-x-seconds-wait-using-javascript here you can redirect using javascript after N seconds

Comment: Cross browser testing is required

Comment: https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204645160/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-meta-tag

Comment: So I have tried javascript `<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = $form->data['curl_data']->url;
    }, 5000);
});
</script>` but it does not redirect with the $form-> data line. Ideas?

Comment: I'm presuming you have installed jQuery? and it should be window.location.href