# Display static page before redirect to the actual backend

Tags: nginx, redirect, haproxy, zope

I have a website with backend which is running with zope + Apache. Now before we decomission the website in 3 months, i would like to display a static page to whomever hits the site  and then after 30 sec redirect to the actual website.Additional limitation is I don't know Zope and don't want to touch existing stack. Is there anyway i could introduce Nginx/haproxy infront and achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your Apache is probably listening to port 80/443 currently.

You need to assign different ports, and let Nginx listen to port 80/443 to Apache, and forward all requests to Apache.

The Zope stack behind Apache does not need to be touched at all.

Comment: It is not about changing the port, Nginx can be installed in different VM. The solution i need is how i display a static page to the user everytime and redirect automatically to the actual backend after 30 sec.

Comment: Then it is even simpler. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150171/page-redirect-after-x-seconds-wait-using-javascript

Comment: Or do you want to show the note for every page? Or just for the start page?

Comment: I need to dispaly the message just for home page.  I have a simple html page i want to dispay under the same url  and reach the actual backend after timeout. The link you shared is appropriate if i redirect from abc.com to xyz.com. Please correct me if i m wrong.